# No longer can create a Python app using "setup.py"

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

I was building apps in Python on a Mac.  it was upgrading.  I upgraded and now the program crashes in setup.py.

The code that I use is

"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

```
Usage:
    python3 setup.py py2app -A
        for this must do rm -rf dist build
        To install a missing package "pip3 install MODULENAME"

    or
    python3 setup.py py2app  for final App

    or

 /usr/local/bin/python3.10 setup.py py2app

"""
from setuptools import setup
APP = ['Analyze pH.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'iconfile': 'SVA.icns',
           'argv_emulation': True}
setup(
    app=APP,
    version='3.5',
    author='Howard Matis',
    author_email='Howard@svadvantage.com',
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

When I run "usr/local/bin/python3.10 setup.py py2app" I get:

```
running py2app
creating /Users/matis/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Silicon Valley Advant/SensTek/pH Analysis/Analyze pH Files - V3.5/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-universal2/python3.10-standalone/app
creating /Users/matis/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Silicon Valley Advant/SensTek/pH Analysis/Analyze pH Files - V3.5/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-universal2/python3.10-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/matis/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Silicon Valley Advant/SensTek/pH Analysis/Analyze pH Files - V3.5/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-universal2/python3.10-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-universal2/python3.10-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-universal2/python3.10-standalone/app/Frameworks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matis/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Silicon Valley Advant/SensTek/pH Analysis/Analyze pH Files - V3.5/setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands

,,,

  q = self._import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1421, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1512, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(co, m)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1719, in _scan_code
    self._scan_bytecode_stores(compile(co, "-", "exec", 0, True), m)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1752, in _scan_bytecode_stores
    for inst in dis.get_instructions(co):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/dis.py", line 288, in get_instructions
    line_offset)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line_offset' referenced before assignment
```

Help.  I cannot figure out what is the problem.  I am doing this on a PowerMac V 12.1.

Comment: setup.py is no longer supposed to be used directly: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html Consider using a build tool such as `pip` instead

Comment: So if setup.py is no longer supported, does anyone have a description of how to build a standalone application written in Python?  My current setup.py procedure now only works for an M1 chip running 12.1. It does not work on Intel machines.   I want others to run this code.

Comment: Just read the article I put there.